# Inline editing with jQuery and jQuery UI without plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, inline-editing

Is there any method to do inline editing for html content without using a plugin. I have already tried with `<div contenteditable='true'>` But I need some more advanced functionality. I don't need to save it to DB on the fly. I am using too many plugins already.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're editing content how come you don't want to save it to a DB? CKEditor has great inline editing capabilities

Comment: I need to save it to DB. But not on the fly. When the form is submitted it will be saved.

Comment: Yes CKEditor is a good bet to do this but it's a plugin. Inline editing can be quite a complicated setup so I wouldn't do it any other way than using a good plugin like that.